# Youtube ContentID getting ownership info through the API using AppsScript

Tags: youtube, google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to get get ownership information against AssetIDs through the Youtube ContentID API.
I can see the data that I need through the API Explorer but cant seem to drill down the data using dot notation.

Here is the output from the API explorer:

```
{
"kind": "youtubePartner#asset",
"id": "A146063471697194",
"type": "music_video",
"ownership": {
"kind": "youtubePartner#rightsOwnership",
"general": [
  {
"ratio": 100,
"owner": "Indmusic",
"type": "exclude"
}
]
},
"ownershipEffective": {
"kind": "youtubePartner#rightsOwnership",
"general": [
{
"ratio": 100,
"owner": "Indmusic",
"type": "exclude"
}
]
}
}
```

When accessing the "owner" I receive undefined instead of the listed value.

```
var url2 = _.sprintf('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets/%s?fetchMetadata=effective&fetchOwnership=effective&key=%s',id,API_KEY);
var result2 = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, getUrlFetchOptions()).getContentText());
Logger.log(result2.ownership.general.owner);
```

returns undefined

I have tried both ownershipEffective and ownership and they are both undefined.
I can log data from result2.ownership.general but nothing below that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell that general is an array by the [brackets] in:

```
"general": [
  {
  "ratio": 100,
  "owner": "Indmusic",
  "type": "exclude"
}
]
```

Try:
Logger.log(result2.ownership.general[0].owner);

general, having been declared an array,  requires a position [0] even though there is only 1 item in the array.